# Generating OAuth Key in distributed deployment of WSO2 API Manager 1.10.0

Tags: api, distributed, wso2-api-manager

Our setup:

- **WSO2 API Manager:** 1.10.0
- **MySQL:** 5.7.12
- **WSO2 API DAS:** 3.0.1
- **OS:** Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

We are using a distributed setup of the api manager with no load balancer (temporarily), based on the configuration and files of this GitHub site:

https://github.com/nuwanbando/wso2-apim-distributed-deployment

but whenever we try to generate an Application Key from a subscribed API, we get the following error:

[image: API Store Error]

From the logs of the Gateway we get (I have organized the logs in order to show the most important aspects):

```
ERROR - AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl Can not create OAuth application  : coreApp_PRODUCTION
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.stub.subscriber.APIKeyMgtSubscriberServiceAPIManagementException: APIKeyMgtSubscriberServiceAPIManagementException


ERROR - APIUtil Error occurred while executing SubscriberKeyMgtClient.
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Can not create OAuth application  : coreApp_PRODUCTION

        Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.stub.subscriber.APIKeyMgtSubscriberServiceAPIManagementException: APIKeyMgtSubscriberServiceAPIManagementException


ERROR - ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor Error occured when updating the status of the Application creation process
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Error occurred while executing SubscriberKeyMgtClient.

        Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Can not create OAuth application  : coreApp_PRODUCTION

        Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.stub.subscriber.APIKeyMgtSubscriberServiceAPIManagementException: APIKeyMgtSubscriberServiceAPIManagementException


ERROR - APIConsumerImpl Could not execute Workflow      
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.WorkflowException: Error occured when updating the status of the Application creation process

        Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Error occurred while executing SubscriberKeyMgtClient.

        Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Can not create OAuth application  : coreApp_PRODUCTION

        Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.stub.subscriber.APIKeyMgtSubscriberServiceAPIManagementException: APIKeyMgtSubscriberServiceAPIManagementException


ERROR - APIStoreHostObject Error while obtaining the application access token for the application:coreApp
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Could not execute Workflow       

        Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.WorkflowException: Error occured when updating the status of the Application creation process

        Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Error occurred while executing SubscriberKeyMgtClient.

        Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Can not create OAuth application  : coreApp_PRODUCTION

        Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.stub.subscriber.APIKeyMgtSubscriberServiceAPIManagementException: APIKeyMgtSubscriberServiceAPIManagementException


ERROR - subscription-add:jag org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: Error while obtaining the application access token for the application:coreApp
```

And the logs of the Key-Manager (I have organized them too):

```
ERROR - CarbonContextDataHolder Cannot retrieve UserRealm for tenant -1 
org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Error occurred while getting tenant user realm for tenant id : -1

        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Tenant ID cannot be -1

ERROR - APIUtil Error occurred while creating OAuthApp admin_coreApp_PRODUCTION
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.mgt.ApplicationMgtUtil.createAppRole(ApplicationMgtUtil.java:142)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.mgt.ApplicationManagementServiceImpl.createApplication(ApplicationManagementServiceImpl.java:129)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.service.APIKeyMgtSubscriberService.createOAuthApplicationByApplicationInfo(APIKeyMgtSubscriberService.java:137)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
...
```

What shall we do in order to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

We need to configure the Keymanager host and port in the following location

/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/api

*AuthorizeAPI*.xml

*RevokeAPI*.xml

*TokenAPI*.xml